# How to extend Entity from AbstractAuditingEntity on Jhipster generated app?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, testing, jhipster

I've generated an entity with the command `yo jhipster:entity MyEntity` (I'm using generator-jhipster@2.19.0 )

and the following options

```
{
    "relationships": [],
    "fields": [
        {
            "fieldId": 1,
            "fieldName": "title",
            "fieldType": "String"
        }
    ],
    "changelogDate": "20150826154353",
    "dto": "no",
    "pagination": "no"
}
```

I've added the auditable columns on liquibase changelog file

```
<changeSet id="20150826154353" author="jhipster">
    <createSequence sequenceName="SEQ_MYENTITY" startValue="1000" incrementBy="1"/>
    <createTable tableName="MYENTITY">
        <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="${autoIncrement}" defaultValueComputed="SEQ_MYENTITY.NEXTVAL">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="title" type="varchar(255)"/>

        <!--auditable columns-->
        <column name="created_by" type="varchar(50)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="created_date" type="timestamp" defaultValueDate="${now}">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="last_modified_by" type="varchar(50)"/>
        <column name="last_modified_date" type="timestamp"/>
    </createTable>

</changeSet>
```

and modify the MyEntity class to extend AbstractAuditingEntity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MYENTITY")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class MyEntity extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {
```

then run `mvn test` and got the folowing exception

```
[DEBUG] com.example.web.rest.MyEntityResource - REST request to update MyEntity : MyEntity{id=2, title='UPDATED_TEXT'}

javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.example.domain.MyEntity] during update time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=createdBy, rootBeanClass=class com.example.domain.MyEntity, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreUpdate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.preUpdate(EntityUpdateAction.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1191)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1257)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:318)
```

this is the test that's failing

```
@Test
    @Transactional
    public void updateMyEntity() throws Exception {
        // Initialize the database
        myEntityRepository.saveAndFlush(myEntity);

        int databaseSizeBeforeUpdate = myEntityRepository.findAll().size();

        // Update the myEntity
        myEntity.setTitle(UPDATED_TITLE);


        restMyEntityMockMvc.perform(put("/api/myEntitys")
                .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(myEntity)))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

        // Validate the MyEntity in the database
        List<MyEntity> myEntitys = myEntityRepository.findAll();
        assertThat(myEntitys).hasSize(databaseSizeBeforeUpdate);
        MyEntity testMyEntity = myEntitys.get(myEntitys.size() - 1);
        assertThat(testMyEntity.getTitle()).isEqualTo(UPDATED_TITLE);
    }
```

the line that's throwing the exception is this

```
List<MyEntity> myEntitys = myEntityRepository.findAll();
```

I've noticed the `TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(myEntity)` method is returning the JSON object representation without the auditable properties -which is expected because of @JsonIgnore annotations- but I suppose the mockMVC.perform update operation isn't honoring the `updatable = false` attribute set on createdBy field

```
@CreatedBy
@NotNull
@Column(name = "created_by", nullable = false, length = 50, updatable = false)
@JsonIgnore
private String createdBy;
```

how may I make an Entity auditable and have the tests passed?

Comment: I've checked this [issue](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/1387) but the problem is a little bit different

Comment: In the meantime I've added a workaround, just set createdBy property to 'system' after restMyEntityMockMvc.perform

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that **transferred (serialized) objects do not include auditable properties** (due to @JsonIgnore annotation), this combined with the @NotNull annotation produces the ConstraintViolation.

1.- One solution is **retrieve first the object we're going to update and then update only the fields you need to.** So, in our example we'll need to modify the update method on MyEntityResource class as follows:

```
/**
 * PUT  /myEntitys -> Updates an existing myEntity.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/myEntitys",
    method = RequestMethod.PUT,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<MyEntity> update(@RequestBody MyEntity myEntityReceived) throws URISyntaxException {
    log.debug("REST request to update MyEntity : {}", myEntityReceived);
    if (myEntityReceived.getId() == null) {
        return create(myEntityReceived);
    }
    MyEntity myEntity = myEntityRepository.findOne(myEntityReceived.getId());
    myEntity.setTitle(myEntityReceived.getTitle());
    MyEntity result = myEntityRepository.save(myEntity);
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityUpdateAlert("myEntity", myEntity.getId().toString()))
            .body(result);
}
```

2.- **Another solution would be to include the auditable fields by removing the @JsonIgnore annotation** on required values from AbstractAuditingEntity.

Which will produce the following response when creating an entity

```
{
"createdBy":"admin",
"createdDate":"2015-08-27T17:40:20Z",
"lastModifiedBy":"admin",
"lastModifiedDate":"2015-08-27T17:40:20Z",
"id":1,
"title":"New Entity"
}
```

so, when updating the entity the request would contain the previous generated values

```
{
"createdBy":"admin",
"createdDate":"2015-08-27T17:40:20Z",
"lastModifiedBy":"admin",
"lastModifiedDate":"2015-08-27T17:40:20Z",
"id":1,
"title":"New Entity Updated"
}
```

and likewise the update response, but **with the lastModified fields updated**

```
{
"createdBy":"admin",
"createdDate":"2015-08-27T17:40:20Z",
"lastModifiedBy":"admin",
"lastModifiedDate":"2015-08-27T17:45:12Z",
"id":1,
"title":"New Entity Updated"
}
```

**Either solution has its own trade offs, so choose what best suits you.**

Also, you should checkout this [issue](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/1774) on generator-jhipster although it's titled as DTO entities only, it's the same problem whether you use them or not.

Answer (score 1):

As I have found on some issue connected to JHipster (can not find the page now I would ref it) the best and easiest solution (to my mind) is this package
[for applying audit on generated entities](https://github.com/hipster-labs/generator-jhipster-entity-audit) .

It consists of everything you need, it also changes changelog files and generates columns in the database: `created_by`, `created_date`, `last_modified_by` and `last_modified_date`.

Best regards